# Getting up to speed on current web service design practices

Tags: rest

I'm admittedly unsure whether this post falls within the scope of acceptable SO questions.  If not, please advise whether I might be able to adjust it to fit or if perhaps there might be a more appropriate site for it.

I'm a WinForms guy, but I've got a new project where I'm going to be making web service calls for a Point of Sale system.  I've read about how CRUD operations are handled in RESTful environments where GET/PUT/POST/etc represent their respective CRUD counterpart.  However I've just started working on a project where I need to submit my requirements to a developer who'll be developing a web api for me to use but he tells me that this isn't how the big boys do it.

Instead of making web requests to create a transaction followed by requests to add items to the transaction in the object based approach I'm accustomed to, I will instead use a service based approach to just make a 'prepare' checkout call in order to see the subtotal, tax, total, etc. for the transaction with the items I currently have on it.  Then when I'm ready to actually process the transaction I'll make a call to 'complete' checkout.

I quoted a couple words above because I'm curious whether these are common terms that everyone uses or just ones that he happened to choose to explain the process to me.  And my question is, where might I go to get up to speed on the way the 'big boys' like Google and Amazon design their APIs?  I'm not the one implementing the API, but there seems to be a little bit of an impedance mismatch in regard to how I'm trying to communicate what I need and the way the developer is expecting to hear my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure wrt the specifics of your application though your general understanding seems ik. There are always corner cases that test the born though.

I would heed that you listen to your dev team on how things should be imolemented and just provide the "what's" (requirements). They should be trusted to know best practice and your company's own interpretation and standards (right or wrong). If they don't give you your requirement (ease-of-use or can't be easily reusable with expanded requirements) then you can review why with an architect or dev mgr.

However, if you are interested and want to debate and perhaps understand, check out Atlassian's best practice here: https://developer.atlassian.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/4915226.

FYI: Atlassian make really leading dev tools in use in v.large companies. Note also that this best-practices is as a part of refactoring meaning they've been through the mill and know what worked and what hasn't).

FYI2 (edit): Reading between the lines of your question, I think your dev is basically instructing you specifically on how transactions are managed within ReST. That is, you don't typically begin, add, end. Instead, everything that is transactional is rolled within a transaction wrapper and POSTed to the server as a single transaction.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not looking to debate anything... just wanting to learn and get on the same page as the guy I'm working with :)

Comment: Ah ok. I guess then, you should continue to understand common practice and then just sit and chat with your dev to understand his (your dev team's) best practices. The atlassian site is a good place to start (as they're refactoring). Also, reading between the lines of your question, I think your dev is basically instructing you specifically on how transactions are managed within ReST. That is, you don't typically begin, add, end. Instead, everything that is transactional is rolled within a transaction wrapper and POSTed to the server as a single transaction.